# Ajax post work but PHP doesn't recognize it

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to store the JavaScript variables which get their values from divs into MySql every 10 seconds. But for some reason the PHP doesn't recognize the variables I'm Posting to it. It displays Undefined Index for all the variables. I tried to use the if(isset($_POST['Joy'])) and the error disappeared but the sql query is never created. 
Here is the HTML code (Note: The HTML is originally provided by Affectiva (https://www.affectiva.com) for the video stream facial emotion recognition system. The code lines followed with // are from the original HTML file. The rest are personal effort to store the values of emotions to the database),

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://download.affectiva.com/js/3.2/affdex.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

 <div class="container-fluid"> //
<div class="row"> //
  <div class="col-md-8" id="affdex_elements" //
  style="width:680px;height:480px;"></div> //
  <div class="col-md-4"> //
    <div style="height:25em;"> //
      <strong>EMOTION TRACKING RESULTS</strong><br> //
      Joy <div id="Joy"></div> //
      Sad <div id="Sadness"></div> //
      Disgust <div id="Disgust"></div> //
      Anger <div id="Anger"></div> //
      Fear <div id="Fear"></div> //
    </div> //
    </div> //
    </div> //
    </div> //

<div> //
  <button id="start" onclick="onStart()">Start</button> //
</div> //
```

Here is the JavaScript code,

```
  var divRoot = $("#affdex_elements")[0]; //
  var width = 640; //
  var height = 480; //
  var faceMode = affdex.FaceDetectorMode.LARGE_FACES; //
  var detector = new affdex.CameraDetector(divRoot, width, height, 
 faceMode); //

  detector.detectAllEmotions(); //
  function onStart() { //
    if (detector && !detector.isRunning) {  //
      detector.start(); //
    } } //

 function log(node_name, msg) { //
    $(node_name).append( msg ) //
  } //

   setInterval(function getElement(){
        var j = Number($("#Joy").text()); //div value
        var s = Number($("#Sadness").text());  //div value
        var d = Number($("#Disgust").text());  //div value
        var a = Number($("#Anger").text());  //div value
        var f = Number($("#Fear").text());  //div value 
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "HTML.php",
    data: {Joy:j,Sadness:s,Disgust:d,Anger:a,Fear:f},
    type: 'POST',
    success : function (){
        alert("sucess");
    }   }); 
  }
    ,10000);

 detector.addEventListener("onImageResultsSuccess", function(faces, image, 
 timestamp) { //

  $("#Joy").html("");$("#Sadness").html("");$("#Disgust").html(""); //
  $("#Anger").html("");$("#Fear").html(""); //

      var joy = JSON.stringify(faces[0].emotions.joy,function(key,val) {
        return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val; //
      });
      var sad = JSON.stringify(faces[0].emotions.sadness,function(key,val) {
        return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val; //
      });
      var disgust = 
     JSON.stringify(faces[0].emotions.disgust,function(key,val) {
        return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val; //
      });
      var anger = JSON.stringify(faces[0].emotions.anger,function(key,val) {
        return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val; //
      });
      var fear = JSON.stringify(faces[0].emotions.fear,function(key,val) {
        return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(0)) : val; //
        });

      log('#Joy', JSON.parse(joy) );
      log('#Sadness', JSON.parse(sad));
      log('#Disgust', JSON.parse(disgust));
      log('#Anger', JSON.parse(anger));
      log('#Fear', JSON.parse(fear));
  });
```

I get the success alert but the database contain nothing. Here is my PHP code,

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'emotions');

if(isset($_POST['Joy'])){
$Joy =  $_POST['Joy'];
$Sadness = $_POST['Sadness'];
$Disgust = $_POST['Disgust'];
$Anger =  $_POST['Anger'];
$Fear =  $_POST['Fear'];

$sql = "Insert into IPEMOTION (JOY, SADNESS, DISGUST, ANGER, FEAR) values 
($Joy,$Sadness,$Disgust,$Anger,$Fear)";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql); }
?>
```

One test I have made is checking the contents of $_POST['Joy'] so I wrote the following code in my php

```
if (!isset($_POST['Joy'])){
 echo "Joy is empty";}
```

after running the code the previous message "Joy is empty" appeared to me.

Comment: `it is not working` ?!

Comment: Yep and I don't know why

Comment: I'm using this code inside a setInterval method. The method is working well unlike the post.

Comment: Do you have a variable with the name `Joy` or `Sadness` .. ?

Comment: Yeah directly defined above the ajax

Comment: Is there any error ?  really _is not working_ does not explain anything!

Comment: No, nothing appears to me. I expect to receive a pop-up window that tells me that either an error or a success has happened but non of these has showed.

Comment: your variable names aren't corresponding with the data you are sending

Comment: @Gobbin, yeh Joy, Sadness aren't variables, that should be j,s ..

Comment: @Gobbin Thank you for your response. I changed the variables but it still not saving data to the database. I noticed that I'm using jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js which excludes Ajax effect. After replacing it with jquery-3.3.1.min.js the Ajax sucess function worked but the data is not saved to database

Comment: @Atheer.sk did you see my answer? Did that work?

Comment: @Gobbin unfortunately no

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @Gobbin I tried to provide the Whole code. Thank you again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your data shouldn't be like that!

From the [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the data should be like this :

```
{variableName: value}
```

So, in your case, the data should be :

```
{Joy:Joy,Sadness:Sadness,Disgust:Disgust,Anger:Anger,Fear:Fear}
```

*Without the quotes (')*

And in `HTMLNew.php` you can do :

```
$joy = $_POST['Joy'];
```

Comment: I tried removing the quotes but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Is there any error ? really is not working does not explain anything! And show the`PHP` code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna keep helping you through the answer section, as it is the most easy way for now. So you are saying that the ajax success alert is popping. Then i think that your `Interval` is not functioning well. Change this:

```
setInterval(function getElement(){
    var j = Number($("#Joy").text()); //div value
    var s = Number($("#Sadness").text());  //div value
    var d = Number($("#Disgust").text());  //div value
    var a = Number($("#Anger").text());  //div value
    var f = Number($("#Fear").text());  //div value 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "HTML.php",
        data: {Joy:j,Sadness:s,Disgust:d,Anger:a,Fear:f},
        type: 'POST',
        success : function (){
            alert("sucess");
        }           }); 
      },10000);
```

Into this:

```
function getElement(){
var j = Number($("#Joy").text()); //div value
var s = Number($("#Sadness").text());  //div value
var d = Number($("#Disgust").text());  //div value
var a = Number($("#Anger").text());  //div value
var f = Number($("#Fear").text());  //div value 
$.ajax({ 
    url: "HTML.php",
    data: {Joy:j,Sadness:s,Disgust:d,Anger:a,Fear:f},
    type: 'POST',
    success : function (){
        alert("sucess");
    }           
}); 
}

setInterval(function() {
  getElement();
}, 10000);
```

Just a few question. To see if your values are right you can `echo $Disgust` in your PHP Script. Then change this:

```
success : function (){
    alert("sucess");
}
```

Into this

```
success : function (data){
    alert(data);
}
```

Then:

```
<?php

//$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'emotions');

//if(isset($_POST['Joy'])){
$Joy =  $_POST['Joy'];
$Sadness = $_POST['Sadness'];
$Disgust = $_POST['Disgust'];
$Anger =  $_POST['Anger'];
$Fear =  $_POST['Fear'];

echo $Joy;
echo $Sadness;
echo $Disgust;
echo $Anger;
echo $Fear;

//$sql = "Insert into IPEMOTION (JOY, SADNESS, DISGUST, ANGER, FEAR) values 
//($Joy,$Sadness,$Disgust,$Anger,$Fear)";

//mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
//}
?>
```

Let me know. I'm deleting all my past answers until now.

Comment: Also in your code the divs `Joy`, `Sadness` etc. aren't containing any value.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: Joy in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML.php on line 33, that what it displays for all the echo variables

Comment: Yes, they contain no values because the values will be appended to them with the log function every time a new value is generated.

Comment: the pop-up message displays the whole code! I don't know why

Comment: Are you sure php is supported on the server?

Comment: @Arjan Yes, I'm using xampp version 5.6.34

Comment: @Atheer.sk You are making lots of mistakes. If your tablename is in small letters then write it as that. Copy the ***EXACT*** name of the table and the ***EXACT*** names of the columns of the database in your code. No wonder it doesn't work. The table doesn't even exists. That is what your code is thinking.